# How to write date in a field with date format?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

[image: Selected by datepicker]
[image: by writing, here is the problem]

I want to write a date at the same time if we  select datepicker that date may select

The date picker code is already working but when I'm trying to write it doesn't show in a date format for example if I trying to write 05/01/2019
it shows as 05012019 I want it as 05/01/2019 format.

```
<div>
<Field name="BirthDate" component= {datepicker} placeholder={'DAY / MONTH / YEAR'}/>
</div>
```

datepicker code

```
 const { input: { value, onChange }, disabled, showTime } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="datepicker">
                <DatePicker
                    selected={value ? moment(value) : null}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    disabled={disabled}
                    format="dd/mm/yyyy"
                    time={showTime}
                />
                <div className="calendar-block">
                    <CalendarIcon onClick={this.datepicker}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: which datepicker you're using because there are too many of them out there

Comment: react-datepicker

Answer (score 3):

Jane Fred

**try like below**

```
const datepicker = ({ input: { onChange, value }, showTime }) =>
     <div className="datepicker">
            <DatePicker
                selected={value ? new Date(moment(value)) : null}
                onChange={onChange}
                disabled={disabled}
                showTimeSelect
                showTimeSelectOnly
                dateFormat="dd/mm/yyyy"
            />
            <div className="calendar-block">
                <CalendarIcon onClick={this.datepicker}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
```

and use it like

```
<div>
<Field name="BirthDate" component= {datepicker} placeholder={'DAY / MONTH / YEAR'}/>
</div>
```

thanks

So, **[more info](https://reactdatepicker.com/)**

Comment: could you share  `datepicker` component over here

Comment: Let me ask 1 thing, how to set showtime in the field?

Comment: please check in answer ` showTimeSelect, timeFormat="HH: mm"` if you need more please click on more info

Comment: I think you don't understand what I'm trying to say, the selected date in datepicker written in the correct format. But the date I write in the field doesn't in the format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195170/discussion-between-vd-virani-and-jane-fred).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to first import Date-picker dependency :

1. **Import datepicker and moment**:

   `import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
    import moment from 'moment';`
2. **Add the html input** as below:

   `<DatePicker
       selected={this.state.selectedDate}
       onChange={this.handleDateChange}
       name="Start Date"
       dateFormat="dd-mm-yyyy"
   />`
3. **HandleDateChange and selectedDate will be as follows**:

   *In your constructor method add :*

   `this.state = {
        selectedDate: moment()
    }`

   `this.handleDateChange = this.handleDateChange.bind(this);`

   *Add this method:*

   `handleDateChange(date){
       this.setState({
         selectedDate: date
       });
   }`